# How to extract strings between two special characters in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, substring

How to write TSQL script to get "Monday_Miami" out of "Email_Monday_Miami_June"

Essentially, I want to extract everything between 1st and 3rd "_"

Thanks a million

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Email_Monday_Miami_June' 

SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @c, 
    CHARINDEX('_', @c) + 1, 
    LEN(@c) - CHARINDEX('_', @c) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@c))
)
```

returns

```
Monday_Miami
```

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @s varchar(max) = 'Email_Monday_Miami_June'

select parsename(replace(@s, '_', '.'), 3)+'_'+parsename(replace(@s, '_', '.'), 2)
```

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks. Already did +1 to your version. Both versions will fail if there are more than 4 words.