# How to extract strings between two special different characters in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I am using the code from the following question:
[How to extract strings between two special characters in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388432/how-to-extract-strings-between-two-special-characters-in-tsql)

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Microsoft.SystemCenter.UserActionManager:ServerName_1.domain.net;ServerName_2.domain.net' 

SELECT SUBSTRING(@c, CHARINDEX(':', @c) + 1, LEN(@c) - CHARINDEX('.', @c) - CHARINDEX(':', @c))
```

Current Result:

```
ServerName_1.domain.net;ServerName_2.
```

I want to search a column/string and extract the string starting at the `':'` and going to the first `'.'`.

The result I am trying to get is: `ServerName_1`

The caveat is that the server name will vary in length.

---

Also, when I try to run the following query:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(Column_Name, CHARINDEX(':', Column_Name) + 1, LEN(Column_Name) - CHARINDEX(':', Column_Name) - CHARINDEX(':', Column_Name))
FROM [dbo].[ServerNameTable]
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Many thanks in advance.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4899/4)

Comment: You need to start by getting the substring that starts at a colon, then using _that_ to locate the first dot within it, if any, and taking that substring. As it is, you pick the first colon and first dot _from the start of the original string_ and that simply won't do. Your second query fails because you subtract the character index of the colon twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will replace everything up to and including the first `:` using `stuff`.  Then it uses that same result to find the first `.` and `substring` the `stuff` result up to the first `.`

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Microsoft.SystemCenter.UserActionManager:ServerName_1.domain.net;ServerName_2.domain.net'

SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX(':',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('.', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX(':',@c), '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that a colon and subsequent dot will always be present.

```
declare @Sample as VarChar(100) =
  'Microsoft.SystemCenter.UserActionManager:ServerName_1.domain.net;ServerName_2.domain.net';

with FiendishThingy as (
  select Substring( @Sample, CharIndex( ':', @Sample ) + 1, Len( @Sample ) - CharIndex( ':', @Sample ) ) as AfterColon )
  select Substring( AfterColon, 1, CharIndex( '.', AfterColon ) - 1 ) as ServerName
    from FiendishThingy;
```