# How to extract a string between two pipe characters?

Tags: regex, db2, substring, db2-luw

In DB2 v10 I have a table with following column values:

```
POST:https:Booking:":getDetails"|26c4ebad-f727-4e59-bcff-3232230ad155|6f9bffbc:85
```

I need to extract a string between two '|' characters as a new column in a `select` statement. DB2 does not seem to have built-in regex support. So far I found out regex-like functions can be registered to DB2 using external libraries, but the article is quite old and things might have changed. What is the easiest method to accomplish this? What would be the method with best performance? If I have to add external libraries, is there a good documentation showing how to add and use them with already compiled libraries if possible?

Note:DB2 running on Linux Intel machine.

Comment: If it's always two pipes, you don't really need regular expressions, do you?

Comment: echo "POST:https:Booking:":getDetails"|26c4ebad-f727-4e59-bcff-3232230ad155|6f9bffbc:85" | sed 's/.*|\(.*\)|.*/\1/'

Comment: AS @mustaccio, said, you can probably use a combination of `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE`.

Answer (score 1):

You might get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388432/how-to-extract-strings-between-two-special-characters-in-tsql). Just need to put your string name and pipe character and adjust query according to your needs.